# flash embed does not load settings.xml

Tags: javascript, html, xml, flash, actionscript

That's it! 
I need to load a graph from an external website on a different HTML file. I copied the embed code for the flash object and changed paths and sources. However, the flash embed would give me the following message:

error loading file: /reports/settings.xml

I can't get out of this. I tried typing in the full src and even creating the file myself taking it from the network window of the inspector, but none of this seems to work. The flash would not display. Here I list the code of the embeded object:

`<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="https://www.website.com/reports/amline" width="100%" height="400" style="undefined" id="am_chart" name="am_chart" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" quality="high" wmode="transparent" flashvars="path=http://www.website.com/external/amline/&amp;data_file=http://www.website.com/reports/748c120eb849d2436b5eeaa852d2df5c/data.xml&amp;settings_file=/reports/settings.xml&amp;preloader_color=#000000">`

There is also this script which seems to be the loader of the flash variables:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // <![CDATA[
  so = new SWFObject("/reports/amline", "am_chart", "100%", 400, "8", "#FFFFFF");
  so.addVariable("path", "/external/amline/");
  so.addVariable("data_file", "/reports/3b34fac79ddaa7876a7ea4408ae80092/data.xml");
  so.addVariable("settings_file", "/reports/settings.xml");
  so.addVariable("preloader_color", "#000000");
  so.addParam('wmode', 'transparent');
  so.write("am_chart");

  function resizeFlashDiv() {
    so.write("am_chart");
    // this is to help browsers repaint the div.
    document.getElementById('am_chart').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('am_chart').style.display = '';
  }

  window.addEventListener('resize', resizeFlashDiv, false);

  // ]]>
</script>
```

I am just stuck in this any help on how to properly embed a flash graph is really appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: What did you got exactly, a 404 error ? Try to use an absolute url for your xml file.

Comment: I did try to use the full url. What I get is a message displayed on the flash embed saying: error loading file: reports/settings.xml If I type in the absolute url nothing would then display. What should I understand out of this?

Comment: Could you verify on your browser network logging tab what's the http code of your xml and it's url ?

Comment: The protocol is https. When I enter the full url the message on the flash embed changes, it states: Error loading file: 
Instead of: Error loading file: /reports/settings.xml

Comment: In that case ( 304 http code ), try to verify the structure of your xml content. If you can give us an url to see the problem directly, that will be more easy to resolve it.